# Filtering data using id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
    [
      {
        "acronym": "VMF",
        "defaultValue": "Video & Audio Management Function",
        "description": "This is defined as the Video and/or Audio Management functionality that can be performed on a Digital Item. The Video & Audio Management functions that will exist on the HDEM platform are as follows:\n· CLIP\n· REDACT\n· THUMBNAIL\n· STILL IMAGE\n· AMALGAMATION",
        "id": "5caddba33a87fd7fa5ee601c",
        "name": "Video & Audio Management Function",
        "updatedBy": " ",
        "updatedDate": "2019-04-07T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {
        "acronym": "",
        "defaultValue": "Url Downloadable",
        "description": "Admin configurable header to denote whether the Digital Item/Data within a URL either via Prosecution Readiness or Assign Digital Data can be downloaded.",
        "id": "5caddba33a87fd7fa5ee6098",
        "name": "Url Downloadable",
        "updatedBy": " ",
        "updatedDate": "2019-04-07T00:00:00Z"
      }]
```

I have this sample json and I want data related to one id how should I get that in react

```
InfoDescription:_.filter(response, (i) => { return i.id === "passing id here"})
```

Using this but not working

Comment: why not dataToFilter.filter(item => item.id === "passing id here?")

Comment: please share the error from the console, or any details on what is not working?

Comment: It's working fine [in the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/y92cnvdk/).

Comment: I also executed this code snippet and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```js
let dataToBeFilter=[
  {
    "acronym": "VMF",
    "defaultValue": "Video & Audio Management Function",
    "description": "This is defined as the Video and/or Audio Management functionality that can be performed on a Digital Item. The Video & Audio Management functions that will exist on the HDEM platform are as follows:\n· CLIP\n· REDACT\n· THUMBNAIL\n· STILL IMAGE\n· AMALGAMATION",
    "id": "5caddba33a87fd7fa5ee601c",
    "name": "Video & Audio Management Function",
    "updatedBy": " ",
    "updatedDate": "2019-04-07T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "acronym": "",
    "defaultValue": "Url Downloadable",
    "description": "Admin configurable header to denote whether the Digital Item/Data within a URL either via Prosecution Readiness or Assign Digital Data can be downloaded.",
    "id": "5caddba33a87fd7fa5ee6098",
    "name": "Url Downloadable",
    "updatedBy": " ",
    "updatedDate": "2019-04-07T00:00:00Z"
  }]



let filteredData=dataToBeFilter.filter(obj=>obj.id=="5caddba33a87fd7fa5ee6098")

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm trying to show default value from data it doesn't give anything ,I'm using this.setstate({ data:filteredData)} and trying to display data.defaultValue

Answer (score 0):

I don't use lodash.

If are just looking for one specific ID in an array I would do it using the native `find` method like this. If you want to get multiple replace `find` with `filter`.

```
const getById = arr => id => arr.find(x => x.id === id)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error on your filter function usage. The first parameter should be a function that return a boolean which determine if the item should included to the new returned Array.

Comment: The syntax is `_.filter(collection, [predicate=_.identity])` [Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter)